# Exclude WooCommerce virtual product from counting towards free delivery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WordPress/WooCommerce website we offer free delivery for all orders over 500 DKK. This is working perfectly fine. We have made a giftcard as a virtual product, seeing as we sent all of our products digitally. The problem is for some reason the virtual product counts towards this 500 DKK free delivery limit.

What we're trying to do is exclude all virtual products from counting towards the free delivery limit.

I have no idea how to go about this. Our website is: http://detitalienskekoekken.dk.linux99.unoeuro-server.com.

The way it is set up is we have a plugin that offers various delivery methods. One of these methods (delivery to a shop) is set to cost 49 DKK but upon reaching 500 DKK you get the delivery for free on this particular option.

I haven't been able to find a code for this online, so I am sorry for not providing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update for your specific plugin:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_free_shipping_option', 15, 2 );
function custom_free_shipping_option($rates, $package){

    // HERE set the "minimum order amount" for free shipping
    $limit = 500;

    $free_total = 0;

    // Get the cart content total excluding virtual products
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual( ) )
            $free_total += $cart_item['line_total'];

    // Set the cost to 0 based on specific cart content total
    if( $free_total > $limit )
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate )
            if( 'pakkelabels_shipping_gls' === $rate->method_id )
                $rates[$rate->id]->cost = 0;

    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

It should work with your specific shipping method.

---

**Original answer** *(for classic "Free Shipping" method)*:

Here is the necessary code that will replace the shipping method Free delivery "minimum order amount" option excluding virtual products:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_free_shipping_option', 10, 2 );
function custom_free_shipping_option($rates, $package){

    // HERE set the "minimum order amount" for free shipping
    $limit = 500;

    $free_total = 0;

    // Get the cart content total excluding virtual products
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual( ) )
            $free_total += $cart_item['line_total'];

    // Disabling free shipping method based on specific cart content total
    if( $free_total < $limit )
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate )
            if( 'free_shipping' == $rate->method_id )
                unset( $rates[ $rate_key ] );

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and working

> So you can even remove this option in the Free delivery settings.

Comment: Not working - my fault. We do not use the WooCommerce free shipping option. We have a plugin with 3 types of delivery (shop, home, business). Upon paying 500 or more the first option becomes free delivery. This works already but currently you can add a virtual product and it counts towards this 500 limit. Perhaps the above code needs to use the specific delivery option that it is related to? The value / name of the delivery option that gives free delivery upon spending 500 or more is pakkelabels_shipping_gls1. Somehow we just need to exclude the virtual products from counting towards this.

Comment: Yeah of course I will do that, it will help a lot of people. Hereby done. The new code you sent still does not work. Is there any way to make it work with this plugin? It is used by 90% of everyone in Denmark and called Pakkelabels, so it would be rather useful. I can provide any extra ID, value or information that is needed.

Comment: After further investigating. Your code removes the option completely, it does not just change the free part of it. Basically the way it is is: Shipping to shops cost 49. If you pay 499 it is free. Here we need the gift card not to count towards the 499.

Comment: Truly amazing. Thank you. I have added marsloic.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code so that virtual products are excluded from the total amount, for free shipping.

Also, it will only show free shipping when available, hiding the rest.

```
function custom_free_shipping_option($rates, $package){
    // HERE set the "minimum order amount" for free shipping
    $limit = 100;
    $free_total = 0;

    // Get the cart content total excluding virtual products
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual( ) )
            $free_total += $cart_item['line_total'];

    //If the total reaches the minimum order, only the free shipping is shown
    if( $free_total > $limit ){
        $free = array();
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;   
    }
    else{
        //If it does not reach the minimum order, the shipments that are NOT free are shown
        $free = array();
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( 'free_shipping' != $rate->method_id ) {
                $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            }
        }
        return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;   
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_free_shipping_option', 15, 2 );
```